# Templates, polymorphism, abstract base class pointers and run-time casting

Tags: c++, templates, casting, polymorphism, rtti

I am wanting to implement a Memento pattern in a game for the purpose of implementing checkpoints.

I have a list of GameObject pointers in the game. GameObject is an abstract class, which is implemented by classes like StaticObject, AnimatedObject etc...

I would like to make my Memento class as abstract as possible, so I have templated my entire Memento system.

my (very barebones, for debugging purposes) Memento class is;

```
template<class T>
class Memento
{
public:
    Memento() { }

    Memento(T data)
    {
        setData(data);
    }
    void setData(T data)
    {
    //wanting this function to do complex behaviour
    }

    T _state;
};
```

I would put in logic to differentiate whether T is a pointer or not later.

_state needs to be a pointer of a copy of the actual GameObject, not just a copy of the pointer itself, as that defeats the purpose of a Memento.

The process of what I would like to do inside the Memento template is;

1) Pass in pointer to abstract base class.

2) Determine type of child class it is pointing to (at runtime).

3) Create a new child class on the heap, whose pointer is _state (from type obtained in 2).

4) Copy data.

The problem I am having is 3. There seems to be no way that I can get the proper type of the child class.

typeid(*data) and decltype(*data) return references to the children. If I try to use auto it is a reference as well. Obviously I can't use new with a reference as the type.

The way around this obviously would be to new the copy of the child class outside of Memento and pass that in. However, I would be interested to know if there is a way of doing it completely in the Template class at runtime. I've been trying to see if I can get it to work for a few hours, and the stubborn part of me does not want to give up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "virtual copy constructor", or clone, idiom.

```
class GameObject {
    ...
public:
    virtual GameObject* clone() = 0;
};

class StaticObject : public GameObject {
    ...
public:
    virtual StaticObject* clone() { return new StaticObject(*this); }
};

//..
```